# What is this used for "-Ddep-type=local" in eclipse VM agrs?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, vmargs

recently i was in an interview in an MNC. There they have shown me this piece of line **-Ddep-type=local** in eclipse's vmargs section and asked what exactly this is used for.Though i am working on eclipse and java for couple of years, i have no idea on what this argument does.Please help me in understanding this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its providing the argument to pick the dependency type, this might be local to their application, where they used this variable 'dep-type' to identify and glue what environment config they want to use

Comment: `-D` means it is an environment variable definition. So it sets `dep-type` to `local`. This is not a standard Eclipse environment variable.

Comment: @greg-449 `-D` sets a Java "system property", not an environment variable. They are separate sets of name value pairs.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes they are setting dep-type to local.But what exactly is dep-type.And it is used for ? BTW thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I don't know, as I said this is not a core Eclipse setting.